# Files.copy(src, dst) throws NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, file, copy, java-io, java.nio.file

The program:

```
    import java.io.IOException;    
    import java.nio.file.*;    
    import java.io.*;

    public class Copier {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            try
            {

                File src = new File("C:\\Users\\k\\Desktop\\sandeep.txt");

                File dstn = new File("C:\\Users\\k\\Desktop\\sandeep1.txt");

                Files.copy(src.toPath(), dstn.toPath());

            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

On my Desktop, `sandeep.txt` exists while `sandeep1.txt` doesn't. I have some text written in `sandeep.txt` that I want to copy to `sandeep1.txt` (after its creation). But when I try to do so, it is throwing the exception: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\k\Desktop\sandeep1.txt`

This question has been asked by someone but is still unanswered so I am asking this again. Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: In the beginning I tried Files.copy(src, dstn) but it didn't work so I tried Files.copy(dstn, src) and it still didn't work. While posting here I forgot to change it back. Now I have corrected it. Please have a look again.

**SOLVED:** I did a mistake while creating the file. I created a new text file and named it sandeep.txt. So effectively this file has name sandeep.txt.txt. I am embarrassed that I did this mistake but I will remember it for long. Can't thank you all enough for giving your valuable time.

Comment: Instead of doing file.toPath(), use Paths.get()...

Comment: `Files.copy(src,dtn)` - that's source, dest.

Comment: @SKG, we should try harder to know the standard libraries. One trick to remember in this particular case is liken it to the Unix `cp` command. Another (very) good practice is to name your variables such that they document your intent (e.g. use `src` and `dest` instead of `p1` and `p2`).

Answer (score 0):

janos is correct that you have the order wrong. However, you can provide a 3rd, a `java.nio.file.CopyOptions` parameter with a few options, the defaults can be found in `java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption`.

common case would look like this:

```
Files.copy(p1.toPath(), p2.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Hello pczeus, I just mistyped while asking. Now I have correctly edited it here. It doesn't seems to work either way. I tried the third parameter but still no luck.

Comment: Try changing your paths to have the '\\` go the other way. Just use '/'.So, for example: "C:/Users/k/Desktop/sandeep.txt"

Comment: I ran this locally, and it worked...as long as the src file existed.

Comment: I did the mistake while creating file. I named it sandeep.txt instead of just sandeep. Thanks for your time

Comment: I still need to earn more reputation to be able to accept an answer.